# How can I show that a function defined by an integral is entire

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

[image: want to show this function is entire]

It is in the form of a Fourier transform, and the question asks to show that this is  entire function of $z$, but I don't know the way to prove that it is entire.

I have tried once using contour integration. Its integral is zero on any circle, but I cannot link it to entireness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint.**

Apply the complex form of [differentiation under the integral sign](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) theorem.

If you define $$f_\alpha(z,t)=e^{-\vert t \vert^\alpha} e^{2\pi i z t},$$ you have $$F_\alpha(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_\alpha(z,t) dt.$$ The partial derivative $$\frac{\partial f_\alpha}{\partial z}(z,t)=2\pi i t e^{-\vert t \vert^\alpha} e^{2\pi i z t}$$ is continuous on $\mathbb C \times \mathbb R$ and we have: $$\left\vert \frac{\partial f_\alpha}{\partial z}(z,t) \right\vert \le 2 \pi \vert t \vert e^{-\vert t \vert^\alpha - 2 \pi \mathfrak{I}(z)t}$$ where $\mathfrak{I}(z)$ is the imaginary part of $z$. As $\alpha > 1$, one can find $1 < \beta < \alpha$ such that $$-\vert t \vert^\alpha - 2 \pi \mathfrak{I}(z)t \le -\vert t \vert^\beta$$ for $t$ in the neighborhood of $\pm \infty$. As $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} 2 \pi \vert t \vert e^{-\vert t \vert^\beta} dt$ converges, $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\partial f_\alpha}{\partial z}(z,t) dt$ also.

Comment: how do we know that its integral is defined for all z?

Comment: I added some lines in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Morera's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera's_theorem) and the related [Cauchy's integral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_theorem) and may be what you're seeking.

$$\oint_\gamma f(z) dz = 0$$

If $f$ is continuous on an open set that contains $\gamma$, and satisfies the above integral, then $f$ is holomorphic on that set (analytic). By extension, if the above integral vanishes for *every* possible $\gamma$, then $f$ is analytic everywhere.

Comment: i proved this: for any circle in the complex plane, the integral over Fa(z) vanishes, but how can i relate this fact to Morera's Theorem?